# Online judging/scoring system

Tags: gratis, web-apps, survey

I would like to get some recommendations for an online judging system.

Some key points:

- We have a competition of academic presentations, in about 20 groups, with 6-10 presenters in each group.
- We would like to judge each group separately.
- We would like to score the presentations based on multiple aspects (5 types of points for each presentation, like content, format, presentation skills, etc.).
- We would like to have data validation for the points (e.g. presentation skilss would be worth more points than content).
- We would like to have multiple judges for each group (10-15 judges).
- Judgement should be available without registration, however some restrictions should be present (e.g. a password that can be reported to judges and a time constraint, so they have to score at the time of the congress).
- Data for the presentations should be imported from an Excel sheet/Google Spreadsheet/similar.
- Judges or contestants should not see the points given by other judges (only the organisers).
- It should be easily handled, as we have some older, more-or-less non-technical judges.
- Automatic calculation of results is not needed, however an Excel output is necessary.
- The judging site should be nicely presented on mobile phones as well.

It can be a self-hosted or third-party solution as well, however it should be private and free (costing no money). Open-source is not a requirement.

I was first trying to do it with Google Forms, which is enough for most of the points, however I can not automate the creation of questions and setting up validation in that, which is quite tedious work to do manually.